# Convert list of objects to map - dart

Tags: dictionary, object, dart

I have a list of the following object

```
class GenesListObj {
  String genesListName;
  String genesList;
}
```

Meaning that the list is `list = [GenesListObj, GenesListObj ,GenesListObj...]`.

I want to be able to convert this list into a map between the object attributes.

The map would look like `{geneListName: [genesList as a list and not a string - separator is ',']...}`

For example for the following list of objects

```
[Obj1, Obj2]

Obj1 - 
  genesListName = 'A'
  genesList = 'a, b, c'

Obj2 -
  genesListName = 'B'
  genesList = 'a, e, d'
```

The expected output would be

```
{'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': ['a', 'e', 'd']}
```

The desired type of the output would be `Map<String, List<String>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
class GenesListObj {
  String genesListName;
  String genesList;

  GenesListObj(this.genesListName, this.genesList);
}

void main() {
  final list = [GenesListObj('A', 'a, b, c'), GenesListObj('B', 'a, e, d')];

  final output = {
    for (final element in list)
      element.genesListName: element.genesList.split(', ')
  };

  print(output); // {A: [a, b, c], B: [a, e, d]}
}
```